# Web Based ADA3D Stl Viewer

Tags: graphics, 3d

I am trying to write a programthat will handle 3D models (.stl files) and show them in a web browser. The problem I have is the most basic of them - where to start?

I have Google-ed it with not much success. Does anyone know of anything that may be able to help?

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need more than PHP to display a three-dimensional image in a web browser...

Comment: This is a very broad question. Anyway, you're going to need something on the client side, not on the server-side. Some 3D viewer written in Flash, Silverlight or, if you're feeling adventurous, HTML5. This is a vast undertaking and it sounds like it might be best for you to start on something simpler first.

Comment: Do you need help with the file format itself or with web part of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP cannot display a 3d model directly. It could be used to render a 2d image of a 3d model, although its not likely to be very efficient.

Comment: This should have been a comment.